# How can I get more experience after beating the game?

Tags: infamous-2

I'm on my second playthrough and I've completed all side missions and collected all dead drops/blast shards. I'm in "Mission 40 Aftermath" after the ending. I still need like 20,000 XP to get unlock all of the powers (good and evil) for the last achievement.

Running around and killing random enemies takes a while, and UGC missions seem to give *very* little XP. I'm evil, so killing hoards of civilians gives me a trickle of XP too, but it doesn't seem very worthwhile.

How can I grind more XP after the end of the game so I can get the "With Great Power Comes Greater Power" achievement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Play on EASY mode for more EXP.

Method One

- Hit someone; heal them. Rinse and repeat.

Method Two

- In Warren, look for conduits spawning spider bots and kill them. (Enviro kill for extra points)

Method Three

- Go to the Northwest corner of the Historic district > The medical clinic. Save and Reload the save.
- Turn right and exit out of the gate. Jump past the raised highway, go right, and then left onto the street below the raised highway. Go forward slightly and you will see about 5 normal Last Sons enemies.
- Try to do a 5-hit melee combo on all of them within 30 seconds for 150 XP points. Reload the save. < Jump in the water!

TIP - Try to implement stunts for bonus XP.